# PostgreSQL query not working in Yii2

Tags: database, postgresql, yii2, database-schema

I want to execute query in my yii2 application. I'm using PostgreSQl. There is a table called **list** inside the **user** schema. If I try to build any query it returns **1**. My code is here:

```
$numUsers = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "user"."list"
')->execute();
```

Please show me my mistake in the query above.

Comment: if this is postgresql why did you tag it as mysql? and what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to the DB type in Yii2 if you want the result of a single value  you should use `queryScalar()` instead of execute()

```
$numUsers = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "user"."list" ')->queryScalar();
```

Comment: Great! Thanks buddy for your help :-)